# Google Drive API - file parents list always nil

Tags: swift, google-drive-api

When I search for files using the Google Drive API with

```
let searchQuery = GTLQueryDrive.queryForFilesList()
```

and print out the parents for each file on completion

```
for file in response.files as! [GTLDriveFile] {
    print("Parents for \(file.name!): \(file.parents)")
}
```

the parents list is always `nil` no matter how many folders the file is located in. Why is this the case?

Here's the complete function I'm using to demonstrate this problem:

```
func searchForAllFilesAndParents(){

    let searchQuery = GTLQueryDrive.queryForFilesList()

    searchQuery?.q = "trashed = false"

    service.executeQuery(searchQuery!, completionHandler: { (ticket: GTLServiceTicket?, response: Any, error: Error?) in

        if let error = error {
            print("Error while searching for all files: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        if let filesList = response as? GTLDriveFileList, let files = filesList.files, !files.isEmpty {

            print("\(files.count) files found)")

            for file in files as! [GTLDriveFile] {
                print("Parents for \(file.name!): \(file.parents)")
            }

        } else {
            print("No files were found")
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out: The request doesn't return the parents list by default so you need to set a fields string, containing the fields that you need. For example, if you need the name, id and parents of a file you add:

```
searchQuery?.fields = "files(id,name,parents)"
```

to the query.

**Important**: Notice that `files(...)` is the new syntax for the v3 API, whereas before it was `items(...)`.